# .Net core Httpclient excutes twice and results in duplicate request

Tags: asp.net, duplicates, asp.net-core-mvc, dotnet-httpclient, asynchttpclient

I am using http client to post payment data to spreedly and charge a credit card. The problem that I am facing is that in some cases its retrying the request second time after 3 secs. The first request has been successful and the card was charged but after 3 secs the httpclient again executes the `postasync()`. I am sure that its not because of duplicate requests from browser because I have logging enabled and the log file only shows logs after the `Httpclient` code which means that there was no second request from the browser or it would have been logged. Following is the code

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_spreedly.API + ":api_key");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

// Get the response.
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
    "https://core.spreedly.com/v1/gateways/" + Gateway + "/purchase.json",
    new StringContent(postBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

// Get the response content.
HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;
string resp = "";
// Get the stream of the content.
using (var reader = new StreamReader(await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
{
    // Write the output.
    resp += await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
}
_logger.LogInformation("Spreedly response for user - {Email} - Response: {Response}", User.Identity.Name, resp);
```

I can see that the log file shows this log "Spreedly response for user" twice after 3 secs. And 2 responses from spreedly are there with different token. Which shows that the transaction was generated twice by `HttpClient`.

Do you think it is retrying the request or something?

Comment: `HttpClient` does not retry, unless you are doing retries in a custom `HttpMessageHandler`.

Comment: I dont have a HttpMessageHandler implemented. Strange why would this happen. Do you think it has something to do with .Net core?

Comment: No, `HttpClient` does not automatically retry POSTs on any platform.

Comment: Weird issue happened to me recently on dotnet 6 blazor. Server requests were slow due to a backup running simultaneously, and request was processed twice. Client side UI doesn't allow this. Looked at server iis logs and it showed two POST requests, one taking 25seconds and another 5 (closer to normal) and finishing at the same exact time. I'm stumped. Did you ever figure this out?